# How to hide rows in a datagridview column in C# SQL visual studio windows form

Tags: c#, sql

IS there a way to hide datagridview rows in C# so that they will appear blank when users view them?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you explain better what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are ways that you can hide rows in a DataGridView, you would use some code like:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row].Visible = false;
```

You may have to set the row to null first like:

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
```

All you needed to do was search this on Google:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/606c4ba0-754e-4789-8d7b-7fc428b76ba6/how-to-invisible-a-row-of-datagridview-?forum=Vsexpressvcs